# AWS Lake Formation: (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetTable operation: Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s) on table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

I have implemented LakeFormation on my data bucket.

I have a step function in which one step consists of running a GlueJob that reads and writes to the data catalog.

I have upgraded my DataLake permissions as reported [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/upgrade-glue-lake-formation.html).

The Service Role that runs my Step Function has a root-type policy (granted just for debugging this issue):

```yaml
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action: 
              - "*"
            Resource: 
              - "*"
```

On lake formation the service role has:

- Administrator Rights
- Database Creation rights (and Grantable)
- Data Location access to the entire bucket (and Grantable)
- Super rights on read and write Database (and Grantable)
- Super rights on ALL tables within above Databases (and Grantable).

The bucket is not encrypted.

But, somehow, its access to the tables is denied with the error:

```
(AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetTable operation: Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s) on table
```

What's really strange is that the Glue Job succeeds when writing to some tables, and fails on others. And there is no real substantial difference across tables: all of them are under the same S3 prefix, parquet files, partitioned on the same key.

Given the abundance of permissions granted, I am really clueless about what is causing the error.

Please, send help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. This is how I solved.

Go to AWS Lake Formation in the console.

Then from the `Permissions` in the drop down menu, click on `Data lake permissions`. Find the principal you are using for your operation. Check if the principal has access to your database. Also check if your `Resource type` is "Database" NOT "Catalog".

To change the resource type to "Database":

1- Go to `Data catalog` -> `Databases`

2- Click on the database you operate on

3- Right top, click on `Actions` -> `View Permissions`

4- Choose your principle, then click on `Grant`

5- Use `Named data catalog resources`

6- Choose your database from the drop down menu

7- LEAVE tables drop down menu EMPTY. I was choosing "All Tables" when I had the error.

8- Select super for database permissions then click on grant.

Once it's working, you can always change the granularity of your permission. Hope it works.